# Check if output file is generated and populated with expected logs - BASH

Tags: bash, file, while-loop

A process (in background) should create a file (e.g. result.txt) and populate it with 5 log lines.

I need to check: 1) if the file exists and 2) checks if all the logs (5 lines) are stored

If these conditions are not satisfy within xxx seconds, the process failed and print "FAILED" in terminal, otherwise print "SUCCEED".

I think I need to use a while loop, but I don't know how to implement these conditions

N.B: the lines are appended into the file (asynchronously) and I don't have to check the compliance of logs, just to check if all are stored

Comment: Are those lines appended to the file? Do you need to be specific on the lines' contents?

Comment: yes, the lines are appended and I don't have to check the compliance of logs, just to check if all are stored

Comment: Then that would mean that you would have to know the number of lines in the file before a new data is appended to it, and check later if another 5 lines were added. Your problem is actually complicated so people could only probably help if you add more info.

Comment: What process does the checking? Is it the same process that sends the logs?

Comment: This is not necessary because if the process succeeds, then I will erase the file in the next steps. So I need to check if the file contains 5 lines (the process in background should produce this output and no more lines)

Comment: these are two different process. I have no control in the first one, the one how create the file and store the logs. My script runs and check if there is a specific file in a path and it contains logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one checks the log and waits 2 seconds before failing:

```
#!/bin/sh

log_success() {
    [[ $(tail -n "$2" "$1" 2> /dev/null | wc -l) -eq "$2" ]]
}

log_success 'file.log' 5 || sleep 2
if log_success 'file.log' 5; then
    echo "success"
else
    echo "fail"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Well here's my draft for that:

```
FILE=/path/to/something
for (( ;; )); do
    if [[ -e $FILE ]] && WC=$(wc -l < "$FILE") && [[ WC -ge 5 ]]; then
        : # Valid.
    fi
done
```

Or

```
FILE=/path/to/something
for (( ;; )); do
    if [[ ! -e $FILE ]]; then
        : # File doesn't exist. Do something.
    elif WC=$(wc -l < "$FILE") && [[ WC -ge 5 ]]; then
        : # Valid.
    else
        : # File doesn't contain 5 or more lines or is unreadable. Invalid.
    fi
done
```

This one could still have problems with race conditions though.